# Best way to sync documents between 2 dual boot PCs

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm going to replace 240GB SSD from laptop with 512GB one. The 240GB is going into my PC as a second drive (2x240GB in PC). I want to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows on both laptop and PC. I would like to have document folder (which shouldn't exceed 8 GB) in sync between all of those devices/systems possibly without duplicating it on single device (I can format those drives freely). What would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If your dual booting on one drive then in addition to the two partitions on there for each OS setup a third partition for file storage, then both OSes can see the files and store them in the same place, no sync needed. In the case of the desktop if you have two drives then if one dual boots then you can use the entirety of the other for file storage.

Comment: But I would like to sync that folder between devices too.

Comment: Partitioning wouldn't stop you doing that. It would be just the same as if you kept your cloud storage on a USB drive. All you'd need to do is make sure you back up the right folder when you set up syncing.